# Explicit Gram Schmidt iteration

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, orthogonality

Let $v_1,...,v_n$ be a set of linearly independent vectors in a real Hilbert space.

Is there a way to write its Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization $w_1,...,w_n$ explicitly only in terms of $v_1,...,v_n$ and inner-products $\langle v_i,v_j\rangle$ in such a way that we do not have to expand anything and can compute $w_1,...,w_n$ directly.

It is clear that this is possible, but most expressions for Gram-Schmidt involve the norm or recursive parts.

Clearly, we start with $$w_1:=\frac{v_1}{\sqrt{\langle v_1,v_1\rangle}}$$
$$w_2:=\frac{v_2-\langle v_2,v_1\rangle v_1}{\sqrt{\langle v_2,v_2\rangle+\langle v_1,v_1\rangle-2\langle v_1,v_2\rangle}}$$

But is there also a general formula for $w_n$?

Comment: The vectors $(w_1, \ldots, w_n)$ are defined iteratively. Expressing $w_1, \ldots, w_n$ _only_ in terms of $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ might lead you to long, not-easily-readable expressions.

Comment: @jibounet and yet they are what I am looking for

Comment: Why do you need to express $w_1, \ldots, w_n$ only in terms of $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ ?

Comment: @because I am using a numerical code that can only access those quantities...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obtain closed-form expressions for $w_i$ using these formal determinants:
$\newcommand\inner[2]{\langle #1, #2 \rangle}$
$$y_1 = v_1$$
$$y_2 = \begin{vmatrix}
        \inner{v_1}{v_1} & v_1 \\
        \inner{v_2}{v_1} & v_2 \\
        \end{vmatrix}$$

$$y_3 = \begin{vmatrix}
        \inner{v_1}{v_1} & \inner{v_2}{v_1} & v_1 \\
        \inner{v_2}{v_1} & \inner{v_2}{v_2} & v_2 \\
        \inner{v_3}{v_1} & \inner{v_3}{v_2} & v_3 \\
        \end{vmatrix}$$

$$\vdots$$

$$y_n = \begin{vmatrix}
        \inner{v_1}{v_1} & \inner{v_1}{v_2} & \ldots & \inner{v_1}{v_{n-1}} & v_1 \\
        \inner{v_2}{v_1} & \inner{v_2}{v_2} & \ldots & \inner{v_2}{v_{n-1}} & v_2 \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\inner{v_{n-1}}{v_1} & \inner{v_{n-1}}{v_2} & \ldots & \inner{v_{n-1}}{v_{n-1}} & v_{n-1} \\
        \inner{v_n}{v_1} & \inner{v_n}{v_2} & \ldots & \inner{v_n}{v_{n-1}} & v_n \\
        \end{vmatrix}$$

Now
$$w_i = \frac{y_i}{\|y_i\|}, \quad i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$$

**Edit:**

To see this, for every $k \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$ we have to prove $[\{y_1, \ldots, y_{k}\}] = [\{v_1, \ldots, v_k\}]$ and $y_k \perp \{y_1, \ldots, y_{k-1}\}$.

We have:
 $$y_k = \begin{vmatrix}
        \inner{v_1}{v_1} & \inner{v_1}{v_2} & \ldots & \inner{v_1}{v_{k-1}} & v_1 \\
        \inner{v_2}{v_1} & \inner{v_2}{v_2} & \ldots & \inner{v_2}{v_{k-1}} & v_2 \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\inner{v_{k-1}}{v_1} & \inner{v_{k-1}}{v_2} & \ldots & \inner{v_{k-1}}{v_{k-1}} & v_{k-1} \\
        \inner{v_k}{v_1} & \inner{v_k}{v_2} & \ldots & \inner{v_n}{v_{k-1}} & v_k \\
        \end{vmatrix}$$

By using the Laplace expansion of the determinant on the last row, we obtain:
$$y_k = \begin{vmatrix}
        \inner{v_1}{v_1} & \inner{v_1}{v_2} & \ldots & \inner{v_1}{v_{k-1}} \\
        \inner{v_2}{v_1} & \inner{v_2}{v_2} & \ldots & \inner{v_2}{v_{k-1}}\\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\inner{v_{k-1}}{v_1} & \inner{v_{k-1}}{v_2} & \ldots & \inner{v_{k-1}}{v_{k-1}}\\
        \inner{v_k}{v_1} & \inner{v_k}{v_2} & \ldots & \inner{v_n}{v_{k-1}}\\
        \end{vmatrix}v_k + \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}(-1)^{k+i}\begin{vmatrix}
        \inner{v_1}{v_1} & \inner{v_1}{v_2} & \ldots & \inner{v_1}{v_{k-1}} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\inner{v_{i-1}}{v_1} & \inner{v_{i-1}}{v_2} & \ldots & \inner{v_{i-1}}{v_{k-1}}\\
        \inner{v_{i+1}}{v_1} & \inner{v_{i+1}}{v_2} & \ldots & \inner{v_{i+1}}{v_{k-1}}\\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
        \inner{v_k}{v_1} & \inner{v_k}{v_2} & \ldots & \inner{v_n}{v_{k-1}}\\\end{vmatrix}v_i$$

Thus $$y_k = \Gamma(v_1, \ldots, v_{k-1})v_k + (\text{linear combination of } v_1, \ldots, v_{k-1})$$ where $\Gamma(v_1, \ldots, v_{k-1})$ denotes the Gram determinant of the set $\{v_1, \ldots, v_{k-1}\}$.

We obtain a lower triangular system:

$$\begin{cases}
y_1 = v_1\\
y_2 = \Gamma(v_1)v_2 + (\text{linear combination of } v_1)\\
y_3 = \Gamma(v_1, v_2)v_3 + (\text{linear combination of } v_1, v_2)\\
\vdots \\
y_k = \Gamma(v_1, \ldots, v_{k-1})v_k + (\text{linear combination of } v_1, \ldots, v_{k-1}) \\
\vdots \\
y_n = \Gamma(v_1, \ldots, v_{n-1})v_n + (\text{linear combination of } v_1, \ldots, v_{n-1})\\
\end{cases}
$$

Since $\{v_1, \ldots, v_{k-1}\}$ is linearly independent, we have $\Gamma(v_1, \ldots, v_{k-1})\ne 0$. Thus, we can solve the system using forward substitution (going downwards from the top) to obtain $v_k$ expressed as a linear combination of $y_1, \ldots, y_{k}$.

This implies $\{v_1, \ldots, v_k\} \subseteq [\{y_1, \ldots, y_{k}\}]$. Together with $\{y_1, \ldots, y_{k}\} \subseteq [\{v_1, \ldots, v_k\}]$ (which we saw from the Laplace expansion), we finally obtain:

$$[\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}] = [\{y_1, \ldots, y_k\}]$$

Now notice (also using the Laplace expansion) that for $i \in \{1, \ldots, k\}$ we have:

$$\inner{y_k}{v_i} = \begin{vmatrix}
        \inner{v_1}{v_1} & \inner{v_1}{v_2} & \ldots & \inner{v_1}{v_{k-1}} & \inner{v_1}{v_i} \\
        \inner{v_2}{v_1} & \inner{v_2}{v_2} & \ldots & \inner{v_2}{v_{k-1}} & \inner{v_2}{v_i} \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\inner{v_{k-1}}{v_1} & \inner{v_{k-1}}{v_2} & \ldots & \inner{v_{k-1}}{v_{k-1}} & \inner{v_{k-1}}{v_i} \\
        \inner{v_k}{v_1} & \inner{v_k}{v_2} & \ldots & \inner{v_n}{v_{k-1}} & \inner{v_k}{v_i} \\
        \end{vmatrix}\\ =
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $i < k$ since it is a determinant with two equal columns}\\
\Gamma(v_1, \ldots, v_k) & \text{if $i = k$}
\end{cases}$$

Thus, $y \perp [\{v_1, \ldots, v_{k-1}\}] = [\{y_1, \ldots, y_{k-1}\}]$

This also implies that $\{y_1, \ldots, y_{n}\}$ is linearly independent, so $y_k \ne 0$. Because of that, it makes sense to define $$w_k = \frac{y_k}{\|y_k\|}$$ Now it is is clear that $\{w_1, \ldots, w_n\}$ is orthonormal, and that $[\{w_1, \ldots, w_k\}] = [\{v_1, \ldots, v_k\}], \forall k \in \{1, \ldots, n\}.$

Comment: Can you also explain how to compute $\left\lVert y_i \right \rVert $ in a closed way?

Comment: @Tokoyo Yes, that's why I said **formal** determinants:
$\newcommand\inner[2]{\langle #1, #2 \rangle}$
$$\begin{vmatrix}
        \inner{v_1}{v_1} & v_1 \\
        \inner{v_2}{v_1} & v_2 \\
        \end{vmatrix} = v_2\inner{v_1}{v_1} - v_1\inner{v_2}{v_1}$$
You can compute them using the Laplace expansion on the last column, like you would do with any determinant.

Comment: and the norm in the denominator, do you also have an expression for that?

Comment: @Tokoyo You would have to expand the determinant and then compute the norm explicitly. If you wish to have a completely closed form, you could define:$$y_2 = \frac{\begin{vmatrix}         \inner{v_1}{v_1} & v_1 \\         \inner{v_2}{v_1} & v_2 \\         \end{vmatrix}}{\left\|\,\begin{vmatrix}         \inner{v_1}{v_1} & v_1 \\         \inner{v_2}{v_1} & v_2 \\         \end{vmatrix}\,\right\|}$$
and so on.
Also, I have added the proof for these expressions.

Comment: This is an absolutely awesome answer.